# How to append a variable to a string in lotus script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

In lotusscript. How do I add a variable to a field name?
i.e I have

```
j=1
getitemvalue("Fieldname"+"j") 
j=j+1 
if j = n then j=1 and Loop
```

So ideally if I put this in a for loop I want to populate fieldname1, fieldname2,...etc. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: getitemvalue("Fieldname"+Cstr(j))

Comment: doc.getitemvalue("Fieldname" & j)(0)

Comment: @D.Bugger: Yes right, thats the "lazy" way as &- operator does an implicit type conversion... Though I like the explicit method more...

Comment: Lazy, yep, that's me. :-)  I hope you noticed the (0) too...

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the value of the variable to a string using the cstr function and then append.

doc.getItemValue("field name" + cstr(j))

Comment: You don't 'need' to do this, but you 'can' do this if you really want to. It will work, but its extra unnecessary syntax. The ' + Cstr(j)' requires the '+' to work out if its a number or string and then call the Cstr function. The '&' syntax is quicker (its been tested) more readable and knows its doing string conversion. So: ''doc.GetItemValue( "fieldname" & j )" is better for me. (Note, don't use spaces in your fieldnames either!). Ampersand will concatenate virtaully any value data type to the string.